# importing images in bulk

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

At the start of my program, I do about 60 of these:

```
parksquare = pygame.image.load("images/parksquare.png").convert()
and then:
window.blit(parksquare...)
```

But this doesn't feel like an efficient way, I know about this way:

```
images = []
for image in os.listdir('images'):
images.append(pygame.image.load(image))
```

But that just appends them to an array and isn't very friendly trying to remember that images[16] is parksquare or whatever, is there anyway around this or to make it easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to build a dictionary instead.

```
images = {}
for image in os.listdir('images'):
    images[image]=pygame.image.load(os.path.join('images',image))
```

Then you can refer to them by their filename, e.g. `images["parksquare.png"]` .

Comment: I get this?   File "C:\Users\ME\Downloads\Python\Sim City\main.py",                   line 150, in <module>
    images[image]=pygame.image.load(image) pygame.error: Couldn't open

Comment: Can you insert the line `print(image)` in front of the `image.load()`? What do you get?

Comment: I did, but I got it working, I had to change the directory to the images folder and it now works, thanks for the help!